# Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f''$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f''$ is bounded. Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$

I am trying to use L'Hospital rule. Please give some hints.

Comment: Duplicate target found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7Df(x)%3D0%24%2C%20AND%20content%3A%24f%27%27(x)%24)

Comment: You just need $f'$ to be uniformly continuous for this to hold.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you could use L'Hopitals rule for this since it requires:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\pm\infty$$
for
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
otherwise you could say:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}1=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$$

---

Obviously for a function to tend to a particular value its derivative must tend to 0.

Comment: I do not think that your last sentence is correct. The existence of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not imply that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: I agree with this.